# Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors

Tags: r, neural-network, classification, confusion-matrix

I use neural network method for prediction for binary classification data
and I try to make a confusion matrix.

The code is

```
train.x_keras.ori<-train%>% select(-stroke) %>% scale() %>% as.matrix()
train.y_keras.ori<-to_categorical(train[,"stroke"])
test.x_keras<-test%>% select(-stroke) %>% scale() %>% as.matrix()
test.y_keras<-test[,"stroke"]
train.x_keras.ori<-array_reshape(train.x_keras.ori,dim=dim(train.x_keras.ori))
test.x_keras<-array_reshape(test.x_keras,dim=dim(test.x_keras))

prop.table(table(train[,"stroke"]))

initializer <- initializer_random_normal(seed = 100)
model2 <- keras_model_sequential()
model2 %>% 
  layer_dense(input_shape = ncol(train.x_keras.ori), # input
              units = 56, activation = "relu", name = "hidden_1") %>%  # hidden layer 1
  layer_dense(units = 28, activation = "relu", name = "hidden_2") %>% # hidden layer 2
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = "sigmoid", name = "output")
model2 %>% 
  compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy",
          optimizer = optimizer_adam(lr = 0.001),
          metric = "accuracy")

history2 <- model2 %>% 
  keras::fit(train.x_keras.ori,
             train.y_keras.ori,
             epoch = 50, 
             batch_size = 50,verbose=T,
             class_weight = list("0"= 0.04775574 ,"1"=0.95224426))

prediction2 <- model2 %>% predict(test.x_keras) %>% `>`(0.5) %>% k_cast("int32")

confusionMatrix(as.factor(prediction2), as.factor(test.y_keras))

# Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : unique() applies only to vectors
```

But I got such an Error message, what can I do for this??

I want to solve that error and make the confusion matrix clearly.

Comment: `prediction2` isn't a vector or matrix - it's a tensorflow object.  If you used `prediction2 <- model2 %>% predict(test.x_keras) %>% `>`(0.5) %>% > as.numeric(.[,2])` instead, that may work.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but when I fix my code like that, the result of prediction2 is all NA

Comment: I think you need to look at what this is: `model2 %>% predict(test.x_keras) %>% >(0.5)` and find a way to turn it into the vector of numbers you want.

Comment: When I do my first try, I want to use 
**prediction2 <- model2 %>% 
          predict_classes(x = test.x_keras)**
but the Error message let me know that 'predict_classes' is not used anymore,
so I have to update my code like 
**model2 %>% predict(test.x_keras) %>% >(0.5)%>% k_cast("int32")**